# How to self reference a record in MySQL in the INSERT INTO SELECT statement

Tags: mysql

I have a tree structure that I store in the table `topic_nodes`.  There is a table called `holders` that all topic node tree belongs to.
Now I need to insert a new ROOT topic node the statement looks like this:

```
        INSERT INTO topic_nodes 
        (id, holder_id, name, level_number, parent_id) 
        SELECT RIGHT(UUID_SHORT(), 10), id, '<ROOT>', -1, <value_of_id_that_was_just_generated> 
        FROM holders;
```

How do I insert the proper value instead of <value_of_id_that_was_just_generated> placeholder?

Comment: please show output of `show create table topic_nodes`

Comment: is there some reason you aren't using the full uuid?

Comment: please show output of `select version();`

Comment: my ids are generated in the app layer. 5.7.29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery that returns the UID, then you can reference that column twice in the main `SELECT`.

```
INSERT INTO topic_nodes 
(id, holder_id, name, level_number, parent_id) 
SELECT uid, id, '<ROOT>', -1, uid
FROM (SELECT RIGHT(UUID_SHORT(), 10) AS uid, id
      FROM holders) AS x
```

Comment: I am getting Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`topic_nodes`, CONSTRAINT `FK_topic_nodes_references_topic_nodes` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `topic_nodes` (`id`))

Comment: I guess it is not possible having that Foreign Key Constraint in place, eh? @Barmar

Comment: Actually, it's worse than that. The problem is that it's not using the same `uid` in both places. It seems to be copying the `RIGHT(UUID_SHORT(), 10)` expression into the outer `SELECT`, so it's generating a different ID for the two columns.

Comment: It doesn't realize that the `UUID_SHORT()` function is not idempotent.

Comment: This seems like a MySQL bug to me.

Comment: But it doesn't work if I hardcode the value for uid instead. Same error.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error if I hard-code the uid value.

Comment: You might get a different error, like a duplicate primary key.

Comment: Actually, it was my bad, it was a different problem... 
But now I cannot remove it as it references self and the foreign key constraint fails the deletion... any way around it?

Comment: If you allow the FK to be NULL, you could insert them all with a null FK, then update them to refer to themselves.

Comment: You could also just leave them as NULL, with the understanding that this is used for the root elements.

Comment: If the parent_id is nullable, I just might keep the parent_id set to null and do not bother with not null constraint and self-reference. I thought it should be easily achievable, but I am stumbling over way too many road blocks.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, just wanted to have an additional guard rail in the form of a not null constraint

Comment: It could probably be done using a stored procedure, but it seems hard to do in a single query.

Comment: Anyways, I am accepting your answer. Thanks for the discussion @Barmar